# Any docs for OWA 2013 calendar integration

Tags: asp.net, exchange-server, outlook-web-app

we're looking at integrating our in house (simple) CRM system with Exchange. I have worked with OWA in the past for email readers (so we can read emails in a mailbox and then process the contents if they have a set keyword and reference). I have not tried working with calendars though.

I have created .ics files and mailed them to the user for creating calendar entries before, but that is not idea. What we would like it to be able to add an entry to a users calendar. We would also like to update the OWA calendar entry if the details change in CRM. Lastly ( and I feel most unlikely) is update the CRM appointment if the OWA appointment changes. there are additional field and follow ups we have from an appointment int he CRM system so we do need a record in CRM.

is this possible?

can anyone point me at some documentation please?

i'm currently using https://exchangeserver/ews/exchange.asmx for the email reader.

we're

Comment: erm, not sure why it's been minus 1 ed. I have tried to research this myself, I have knowledge of the subject and am asking for help. As it turns out the reason I can't find anything every useful is because I am searching with OWA instead of EWS. Now I am searching for EWS I can find useful information. thanks to the answer from Venkat! seriously the SO community can be quick to dismiss peoples questions I see it a lot on the IOS threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Office 365, you can create/modify/delete/read calendar information that shows up in OWA, using [Office 365 Calendar REST APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/calendar-rest-operations).  See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/HowTo/setup-development-environment#bk_VisualStudio) for getting started for .NET development.

If you need to support on-premises Exchange as well, you can use our older SOAP API - Exchange Web Services.  This is what you are calling at present for your email reader. Best way to call EWS for .NET is using EWS Managed API ([GitHub](https://github.com/officedev/ews-managed-api), [Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/jj220535(v=exchg.80).aspx)).  You can also take a look at [code samples for EWS Managed API](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Exchange-2013-101-Code-3c38582c) to learn about accessing calendar.

Comment: Venkat - thank you very much! the biggest problem as I noted above is I was searching for OWA integration, and finding nothing, not EWS (stupid me). Thanks very much to the pointer for the docs!

Comment: James - Are you looking for a deeplink to view an existing calendar event in OWA?